# Hello, are the 2.4 Ghz and 5 Ghz bands seperated ? my family is clogging my internet connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, wireless-router, connection

I have a 2.4Ghz single band router. technicolor I am planning on purchasing a new dual band router. Since my family is clogging my internet connection traffic with movies and series i am planning on purchasing a new dual band router and broadcast two different networks. I would let them connect to the 2.4 Ghz band and i connect myself alone to the 5 Ghz band. Does this solve my problem ? i want to get rid from this clogging problem and i don't want anyone to interfere or slow my internet connection.

Comment: You could set a rate limit on their wireless connection, so they don't leech your entire bandwidth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is not going to solve your problem.

The 2.4 Ghz and 5Ghz are for wifi, and yes they are separate. This is the connection from your local device to the router. The connection from the router to the internet remains unchanged no matter what you do. If your internet speed is not capable of sustaining all your devices, it doesn't matter if you go through 5Ghz or not, and the bottleneck is not your wifi, but the internet itself.

That said, 2.4Ghz is a slow network, and 5Ghz is a fast network. You may see some improvements in speeds, but if clogging really is the problem, it will not be the answer to switch to 5Ghz.

Comment: Oh okay. So is there any way not to be affected by the people connected to my home network ?

Comment: If you want to check ifbthr problem is WIFI, try plug your computer into a network cable. If it goes away its WIFI and your upgrade should work. The way to make you not affected is to limit Th speeds other people have - find a router that supports QoS and rate limiting.

Answer (score 1):

If they're saturating LAN, it will help. If they're saturating your Internet connection (more likely), it won't help. Wi-Fi is used only between your router and connected devices and its throughput is usually way higher than Internet connection speed.

5 GHz band doesn't give you extra Internet bandwidth, it gives you extra router bandwidth.

Comment: Oh okay. So is there any way not to be affected by the people connected to my home network ?

Comment: Get a separate Internet connection for yourself. Alternatively get a QoS-capable router, but configuration may not be obvious if you're not familiar with networking.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the 2.4 gig and 5 gig band are separate, and your proposal feasible.

Note that it may not be your family saturating the 2.4 gig band (but this is possible), it could be interference from neighbours. If your family is torrenting make sure your new router can handle the connection tracking requirements. You may also want to look into QoS as its possible the bottleneck is/will become your Internet connection - especially the upload if you are using an adymetric connection like VDSL.

Comment: Thank you. I found that when they open youtube and start streaming movies. They are affecting my bandwidth on the same network since my internet speed goes down when they do so

Comment: So if connecting alone to a 5Ghz connection but from the same isp solves the problem then be it. I will purchase a dual band router then

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will not solve the issue. Yes, they are separate, but as stated in my answer, I'm pretty sure the problem lies on the internet connection itself, not the 2.4 Wifi.

Comment: There's also the issue that your router will naturally prioritise streaming services, youtube etc over less time-sensitive transmissions [which will include gaming].